# Multiple Google Play Services library Versions

Tags: android, google-play-services

According to Android developer documentation, Google Play Services library provides an interface to the hosting application so that, at runtime, it can access to Google Play services APK through interprocess communication.

Considering the following configuration where an android application includes Google Play Services library and a SDK that also includes Google Play Services library, as shown below:

- MyApplication

  - Google Play service v.XX
  - MySDK

    - Google Play Services v.YY

Since the SDK and the hosting application include different versions of Google Play Services library, is version YY fetched at MyApplication build time instead of version XX ? Is the final application built with the two different versions (XX and YY) and in this case which one is called at runtime?

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2):

You can use command ./gradlew app:dependencies at Android Studio console to see all dependencies and which version is being used.